# SelectWidget Ipython Bug

Tags: python, selection

I think there is a very wierd bug in SelectWidget,

```
date = SelectWidget(values = ['12-Mar-15-fullfeed.csv',
 '4-Mar-15-fullfeed.csv',
 '9-Mar-15-fullfeed.csv',
 '2-Mar-15-fullfeed.csv',
 '6-Mar-15-fullfeed.csv'])
display(date)
```

It doesn't display '2-Mar-15'
If I change the first entry from 12 to 31 it does...and if I change to 32 it still doesn't display 2-Mar-15. So if "2" is used in the first entry it somehow hides 2-Mar-15....perhaps comparing it to other values for equality.

Anyway its a bug!!!
Or is it something interesting??

Answer (score 0):

The quickfix is to use a dictionary with zip function. Something I realized from haskell!

```
date = SelectWidget(values = zip (np.arange(10000), ['12-Mar-15-    fullfeed.csv',
 '4-Mar-15-fullfeed.csv',
'9-Mar-15-fullfeed.csv',
 '2-Mar-15-fullfeed.csv',
 '6-Mar-15-fullfeed.csv'])))
```